# How do I remove a Guix gc-root

Tags: guix

When I list my current Guix garbage collection roots I find a root that I want to remove, the last one which belongs to a project I no longer develop.

```
$ guix gc --list-roots
/var/guix/profiles/per-user/rovanion/current-guix-30-link
/var/guix/profiles/per-user/rovanion/current-guix-30-link
/var/guix/profiles/per-user/rovanion/guix-profile-133-link
/var/guix/profiles/per-user/rovanion/guix-profile-133-link
/var/guix/profiles/per-user/rovanion/current-guix-30-link
/home/rovanion/source/python/a-project/.direnv/.guix-profile
```

Reading the manual page [Invoking guix gc](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Invoking-guix-gc.html) I find instructions on how to add additional roots but nothing on how to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the path

```
rm /home/rovanion/source/python/a-project/.direnv/.guix-profile
```

after that, `guix gc --list-roots` should not show it anymore

and the next run of garbage collecting will remove the files

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I also had to remove the root in

```
/var/guix/gcroots/auto/$hash
```

that corresponds to the symlink in

```
ls -l /home/rovanion/source/python/a-project/.direnv/.guix-profile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rovanion users 36 Mar 24  2020 /home/rovanion/source/python/a-project/.direnv/.guix-profile -> /var/guix/gcroots/auto/$hash
```